# How to send file to user with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Here's my old code to sends a file to the browser:

```
def show
  send_file File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'price.xls')
end
```

But recently I've found out that tmp folder can't be used as a persistent storage on Heroku, so I decided to move the file to AWS S3.

That's what I've got so far:

```
def show
  uploader = PriceUploader.new
  uploader.retrieve_from_store!('price.xls')
end
```

Now, how do I send the file to the browser?

**upd**

I itentionally didn't mount the uploader

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
def show
  uploader = PriceUploader.new
  uploader.retrieve_from_store!('price.xls')
  uploader.cache_stored_file!

  send_file uploader.file.path
end
```

Comment: I tried this, but had trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179553/download-a-carrierwave-upload-from-s3
    
Any ideas?

Comment: The blog post doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
# find  uploader ...

send_file(uploader.path,
         filename: uploader.filename,
         type: "application/<some-type>")
```