# Download a Carrierwave upload from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, download, carrierwave

I'd like to download an image that was uploaded to S3 using carrierwave.  The image is on the Card model, mounted as an uploader.  I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193516/how-to-send-file-to-user-with-carrierwave), but had trouble getting that solution to work.  My code is:

```
#download image from S3
uploader = card.image       #image is the mounted uploader
uploader.retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(card.image.url))
uploader.cache_stored_file!
```

that last line throws: "... caused an exception (undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass)..."

My carrierwave config looks like:

```
#config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/upload"
  ...
end
```

Comment: you could do: `file = open card.image.url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving). It was as easy as:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image::open(card.image.to_s)
image.write(somepath)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that imagemagick could download and save files this way, only with the URL, nice!

Comment: can you further elaborate how this works? where would this code go?

Comment: I've got that code in a custom background job that downloads images from S3. It could be anywhere though.

Comment: @joseph.hainline i want to give a download option to user, how can i specify path here where you have written somepath because i don't know about the user's system

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this in Rails 5 to download file from AWS S3.

```
def download
  image = card.image

  # validate existing image from AWS S3
  if image.try(:file).exists?
    data = open(image.url)
    send_data data.read, type: data.content_type, x_sendfile: true
  end

end
```

I hope help everyone.